# Unable to connect from Spring Boot to Dockerized Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have a spring boot rest service running on windows 10 machine and I have Redis running on a docker container. Now, I want my Spring Boot to connect to the redis container, however, it is always giving me the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: redis
```

My **application.properties**, contains the following:

```
# Set Redis server and Jedis settings
spring.redis.host = redis
spring.redis.port = 6379
spring.redis.password = test123
spring.jedis.connection.timeout = 60
```

and this is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    container_name: 'redis-cache'
    environment:
       - REDIS_PASSWORD=test123
       - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: nodeport
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis_data:/bitnami/redis'
    networks:
      - app-tier
volumes:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: If you are starting redis container and spring boot application on the same host? Or different host? spring.redis.host should be the host name/ip where you are staring redis container. Make sure the host/ip is resolved from the machine where spring boot application is running.

Comment: Basically, the spring boot application is on my local development machine and I just spawn a docker container with redis in it on the same machine. Not sure how to resolve host/ip from the machine where my spring boot is running though, sorry new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set spring.redis.host = localhost in application.properties.

Since the current value set is 'redis', application is not able to find this host and hence you are getting unknownhost exception.

Comment: Yes, setting the spring.redis.host to localhost works! Thank you S.K.